# /usr/local/bin/python3: No module named pip Error on or near line 85; exiting with status 1

Tags: apt, software-installation, pip, jupyter

I am installing [Intel OpenVINO Toolkit](https://software.intel.com/en-us/openvino-toolkit) in which I configure the model optimizer.

```
(ankit) ankit@ankit-HP-Notebook:~/intel/computer_vision_sdk_2018.3.343/deployment_tools/model_optimizer/install_prerequisites$ sudo ./install_prerequisites.sh
Hit:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [107 kB]     
Hit:4 http://archive.canonical.com xenial InRelease                            
Get:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]    
Get:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [107 kB]  
Get:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-proposed InRelease [260 kB]
Fetched 583 kB in 2s (287 kB/s)   
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
21 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-venv is already the newest version (3.5.1-3).
libgfortran3 is already the newest version (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10).
python3-pip is already the newest version (8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 21 not upgraded.
/usr/local/bin/python3: No module named pip
Error on or near line 85; exiting with status 1
```

I have tried many things, so how can I solve it?

[image: I have tried many things]

Comment: You appear to have a non-repository version of python `/usr/local/bin/python3` - what is this, and how/why did you install it?

Comment: Run `source deactivate` and  `sudo ./install_prerequisites.sh`

Comment: Check the script you are using. BTW steeldriver, does it matter? Pip has nothing to do with python3 at all so. It should be pip3. But I get your point..

Comment: Run source deactivate and sudo ./install_prerequisites.sh – abu_bua                        it neither change in little bit can you explain me the line more better ,it shows same thing ,  i am installing openvino toolkit

Answer (score 15):

It means you need to install pip using this commmand-

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

if python3 is the only version of python installed then `pip` should invoke pip3 when used.

Answer (score 4):

Because you have `python3-pip` package installed, you need to invoke that as `pip3`:

```
pip3 list
sudo pip3 install virtualenv
```

Comment: it not works as in my case

Comment: abu_bua it shown same as previous

Comment: Run source deactivate and sudo ./install_prerequisites.sh – abu_bua  it neither change in little bit  can you explain me the line better.

Answer (score 0):

Create a symbolic link at `/usr/local/bin/python3/pip` which references to file `/usr/local/bin/pip2.7`.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip2.7 /usr/local/bin/python3/pip
```

Then change directories to `~/intel/computer_vision_sdk_2018.3.343/deployment_tools/model_optimizer/install_prerequisites` and run `sudo ./install_prerequisites.sh`