# E: Unable to locate package Pyaml

Tags: package-management, python, intel, pip, anaconda

```
(ankit0) ankit@ankitG-PC:~/intel/computer_vision_sdk_2018.3.343/deployment_tools/demo$ sudo apt-get install Pyaml
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package Pyaml



(ankit0) ankit@ankitG-PC:~/intel/computer_vision_sdk_2018.3.343/deployment_tools/demo$ ./demo_squeezenet_download_convert_run.sh


###################################################



Downloading the Caffe model and the prototxt
Installing dependenciesstrong text
Run sudo -E apt -y install build-essential python3-pip virtualenv cmake libpng12-dev libcairo2-dev libpango1.0-dev libglib2.0-dev libgtk2.0-dev libswscale-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libgstreamer1.0-0 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base
[sudo] password for ankit: 
Hit:1 http://storage.googleapis.com/bazel-apt stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease               
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [107 kB]
Get:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial InRelease [65.8 kB]      
Hit:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease             
Hit:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease           
Hit:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-proposed InRelease            
Hit:8 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease            
Fetched 173 kB in 1s (122 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version (12.1ubuntu2).
libcairo2-dev is already the newest version (1.14.6-1).
libpango1.0-dev is already the newest version (1.38.1-1).
cmake is already the newest version (3.5.1-1ubuntu3).
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base is already the newest version (1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2).
libglib2.0-dev is already the newest version (2.48.2-0ubuntu4).
libgstreamer1.0-0 is already the newest version (1.8.3-1~ubuntu0.1).
libgtk2.0-dev is already the newest version (2.24.30-1ubuntu1.16.04.2).
libpng12-dev is already the newest version (1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1).
libavcodec-dev is already the newest version (7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
libavformat-dev is already the newest version (7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
libswscale-dev is already the newest version (7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
python3-pip is already the newest version (8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4).
virtualenv is already the newest version (15.0.1+ds-3ubuntu1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.15.0-30 linux-headers-4.15.0-30-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-30-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-30-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-30-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
The directory '/home/ankit/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/ankit/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (3.13)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (2.9.1)
Run /home/ankit/intel/computer_vision_sdk_2018.3.343/deployment_tools/demo/../model_downloader/downloader.py --name "squeezenet1.1" --output_dir "/home/ankit/openvino_models"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ankit/intel/computer_vision_sdk_2018.3.343/deployment_tools/demo/../model_downloader/downloader.py", line 21, in <module>
    import yaml
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml'
Error on or near line 132; exiting with status 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `apt` package for the PyYAML library for Python 3 is named `python3-yaml`. You can install it with:

```
sudo apt install python3-yaml
```

Alternatively, if you want to install it using `pip` from PyPI instead of the Ubuntu repositories (recommended mainly for virtualenvs, not so much for system-wide installation), you would need `PyYAML`:

```
python3 -m pip install PyYAML
```

Comment: thank you
Byte Commander face one more problem for 3 days  bcoz i stuck and can't think more can you help in this also  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068922/usr-local-bin-python3-no-module-named-pip-error-on-or-near-line-85-exiting-wi

Comment: Next time i ask and write properly